# std::string::reserve not being honored to create std::string of exact capacity

Tags: c++, string, memory

I am trying to allocate strings of exact capacity. This is being done to save on memory. The size of strings to be created is variable, but known before hand.

I am trying to use reserve, but the capacity not honored and over-allocation is taking place.

```
  std::string str;
  str.reserve(21);
  str = "12345678901234567890";
  std::cout << "size: " << str.size() << "\n";
  std::cout << "length: " << str.length() << "\n";
  std::cout << "capacity: " << str.capacity() << "\n";
```

The output of the above is as follows:

```
size: 20
length: 20
capacity: 30
max_size: 9223372036854775807
```

I know that reserve is a non-binding request as described [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/reserve/)

Is there some method to ensure that strings of exact size are allocated.

Comment: To save on memory you would be much better off not using a separate allocation for every string

Comment: @MM the requirement of the application needs storage of seprate strings. So seperarate allocation is a nessacity.

Comment: The argument to `reserve` is only the expected size but the implementation is free to allocate whatever is deemed sensible: http://eel.is/c++draft/string.classes#string.capacity-11

Comment: There is a constructor which takes a count and a char, forcing the string to a certain size: `std::string str(20,'\0');`

Comment: Even writing `new char[20]` does not guarantee that you will take exactly 20 bytes from heap memory. In your case it may well be that your implementation knows that a size of 30 bytes uses no more heap memory than a size of 20 bytes, so you get the extra 10 bytes for free. If you want to control allocation write your own allocator.

Comment: @HenriMenke Thanks for your suggestion. It Worked. please add it as an answer too.

Comment: Implementations of the C++ Standard Library also frequently apply _small string optimization_ for `std::string`. With this technique, even empty string has some capacity completely for free (without dynamic memory allocation). For instance, with Clang (libc++), size of `std::string` is 24 bytes and even empty string has capacity 22 bytes, which I guess is given by SSO.

Comment: @HenriMenke, that guarantees size, not capacity.

Answer (score -6, accepted):

You can use the following :

```
std::string str;
str = "12345678901234567890";
str.shrink_to_fit();
```

The output is as follows:

```
size: 20
length: 20
capacity: 20
```

Comment: It does not work in general. For instance, with Clang, `shrink_to_fit` does not change the capacity of a short/empty string: https://wandbox.org/permlink/t79KHC7NSefoO3PS.

Comment: This happens to work on some implementation, but it's just an implementation detail - `std::string` is always free to overallocate, and `shrink_to_fit` is both a non-binding request, and even when it does something it's free to round the resulting capacity however it likes most. Also, SSO generally results in strings that just cannot have a smaller capacity than some fixed value.

Comment: This is a *request* and is therefore no better than the constructor methods mentioned in the comments. While some *implementations* may honor it, the standard doesn't mandate that. Capacity is not something you control.

Answer (score 4):

In short: **No**, there isn't.

You can precisely control the **size** of a `string`, but not its **capacity**. C++ puts no restriction on what capacity implementations should take -- the implementation can choose whatever that (it thinks) is efficient. Only the size is fixed.

P.S. Several tens of bytes are usually not considered a waste of memory. STL containers are designed for a compromise between time efficiency and space efficiency.